# What is the easiest way for me to download all my comments across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, comments

The FAQ says: [Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), meaning that [we should not expect them to be around forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

So I would like to backup all my comments on a regular basis: what is the easiest way for me to download all my comments across all Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Why would you want to _backup all my comments on a regular basis_?  What's the point?  As a side note, you can search comments via the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do you have comment that it would be bad if they were deleted? If so edit it into a relevant question/answer or make an answer from it

Comment: You have some stringent data-retention policies! ;)

Comment: It's already backedup for you. Just learn to use SQL

Comment: @bluefeet & AB: As a rule, I don't like to have stuff I wrote being deleted without at least being sent a copy of it, as I can need it later for various purposes, ranging from remembering some ideas to training some voice recognition engine. I indeed have stringent data-retention policies: I am a strong believer in data liberation, and wish StackExchange paid more respect to user-generated content (I'm actually even more annoyed that [we cannot retrieve our answers to deleted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/178179) (and as you know questions do get deleted from time to time).).

Comment: RichardTingle: content that can be useful for me for later use is not restricted to answers. ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: yes one of the solution I was hoping for was some already-written SQL query. I know SQL but it would be even faster it is already available. I'll give a shot then!

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I've just written an SQL query to retrieve all comments for a given user: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150358/display-all-comments-of-a-given-user . It's actually pretty good, the only issue is that it needs to be run for each Stack Exchange website.

Answer (score 9):

"Back them up" by editing them into a question or answer. They'll quickly be mirrored across The Internet.

Comment: What should happen when someone knows enough to spot an error in an answer (and thus comments), but not enough to provide a full alternative answer?  (Assume the answerer disagrees that this is a problem.)  As an asker, or other person reviewing a question looking for a solution, I'd sure want to know about issues with a proposed approach.  Where should those comments go?

Comment: If a correcting edit is rejected, they *should* go in another answer, @Monica. If the author lacks sufficient knowledge to write one, then hopefully someone else will be able to.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and run this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/150358/display-all-comments-of-a-given-user) (thanks bluefeet and ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd for the suggestion).

```
-- Display all comments of a given user

DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT Comments.Text
FROM Comments
WHERE Comments.UserId = @UserId
```

The main issue is that it needs to be run for each Stack Exchange website you want to retrieve your comments from, which can be pretty tedious to do.

Comment: Odd, edge-case problem (I understand, but just disagree with your reason for it); but good solution!

Answer (score 5):

You can download a Stack Exchange [GDPR data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/gdpr/request) of your own content, and extract your comments from the respective `PostComments.json` file.

It looks like even the comment revision history is included, which is normally inaccessible to users who are not moderators.

I wrote [an answer to *Dump of my own Stack Exchange content*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336743/157730) which discusses the process in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Just [download the entire data dump of the site](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/).  That'd be the easiest option anyway.  Getting just your comments out of it would be a bit more involved though.